# How to create a custom TextView Background Android?

Tags: android, textview

I want to create a background for my TextView to look exactly like this one(Yellow Box). 
[image: text view with background]

After I create the image how do I go about setting the background to the TV?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for that you create simple image . then Convert in to nine patch [here](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html)

after set background to that drawable

Example of Nine patch Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you could create a shape drawable.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<solid android:color="@color/Yellow" />
<stroke android:width="@dimen/" android:color="@color/"/> 
<corners android:radius="@dimen/"/>
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/"
    android:centerColor="@color/"
    android:endColor="@color/"
    android:centerX="0.5"
    android:centerY="0.5"
    android:gradientRadius="100"
    android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done using shape attribute.

I created a similar one for myself using the below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:padding="10dp"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

  <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" /> //This should be the yellow color you want

  <corners android:radius="5dp" /> //for rounded corners

   <stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/color_dark_blue" /> //for border if you wish any

</shape>
```

Create it as an xml file inside drawable (say myTextViewBg.xml).

Then add it as a background to your TextView as,

```
yourTextView:background="@drawable/myTextViewBg.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set background of your textview 
`android:background="@drawable/myResouce"`
or using java
`mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myResouce);`

But in your case create a relative layout then put an imageView and Textview inside it and adjust it according to your view.

In `imageView` use image which you in your question, expect text to change. And in `textView` use changeable text. Which you may change pragmatically as well.