# Custom TextView background

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-custom-view

I would like to create TextView with custom baground such as

[image]

but unfortunatelly I have no idea how to do it. Maybe someone knows how to create the background in xml (not in java code)? Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268717/how-to-create-a-custom-textview-background-android

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setBackgroundResource(int resourceId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29) in code or `android:background` in your layout.

Java:

```
mTextView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourDrawable);
```

Layout:

```
<TextView
    android:background="@drawable/yourDrawable"
    ...
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a layout like this. You have to use the custom image for this. 
Your code goes here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="your_custom_image"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="text_goes_here"
        android:textColor="specify_color" />

</LinearLayout>
```